# How to render a Views Content Pane programmatically?

Tags: 7, views, chaos-tool-suite

I have a view which displays all content of type "news" which is tagged with a specific tag, e.g. "world" (passed as parameter to the view).

The view machine name is `news`. It has a display of type Content Pane (machine name `panel_pane_1`). It also has a contextual filter set to "field_tags".

How to render this view content pane programmatically, passing tag value "world" to it?

(I've found `ctools_content_render` but no idea if this is the right function for this task and how to use it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

[`views_embed_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

e.g

```
print views_embed_view('news', 'panel_pane_1', 'world');
```

Any additional parameters will be passed as arguments, i.e contextual filter values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views_content_views_panes_content_type_render()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!views_content!plugins!content_types!views_panes.inc/function/views_content_views_panes_content_type_render/6). Here is a detailed example:

```
  // Important to include target content type.
  // You can also use 'views' content type but with a different render function.
  module_load_include('inc', 'views_content', 'plugins/content_types/views_panes');
  // Use your views machine name and display name here.
  $subtype = 'views_name-display_name';
  // Adjust settings to yours. You can debug ctools_content_render to see
  // all available settings in $conf. Or check
  // views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane::option_definition().
  $conf = array(
    'items_per_page' => 2,
    'offset' => 0,
    'more_link' => 1,
    'override_title' => 1,
    'override_title_heading' => 'blablalba',
    'override_title_text' => '',
    'pager_id' => 0,
    'use_pager' => 0,
  );
  // (optional) Prepare ctools context and context keys if your argument type
  // is 'context'. Check handling of other argument types in
  // views_content_views_panes_content_type_render().
  $conf['context'] = array('mycontext');
  $context = array(
    'mycontext' => ctools_context_create('node', $node),
  );
  // Render views pane.
  $pane = views_content_views_panes_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context);

  // Get pane HTML.
  $output = render($pane->content);
```